# sort list on reference table's column name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using mvccontrib with entity framework in my mvc project and want to add functionality to sort by column name. By using single table it is  simple. But in my case one table is referenced in other tables. Like Table Employee, EmployeeDetails, States.
States is linked with EmployeeDetails and EmployeeDetails is linked with Employee table.

I want to sort the grid on the click of Employee name, Employee Details and state.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good sample on ASP.NET official web site:

http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application